# "type is not allowed" tslint.json issue. How to Ensure the configuration meets with what you set up on tslint.json

Tags: json, angular, debugging

Ng serve just works fine but when I try to build the project it says
"type is not allowed" in  tslint.json issue. How to Ensure the configuration meets with what you set up on tslint.json

Answer (score 0):

running this command to deploy the app fixed it.. ng build --env=prod

found the solution in github